# How do I improve the code (C#) to open the specified excel file and not only the excel application

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm pretty new to this. I want to create a Microsoft Excel add-in that opens a specific Excel File and writes some data. The problem is my code is only opening the excel application and not the specified file
Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;

namespace ExcelAddInTrial
{
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\Microsoft\B1.xlsx");
    }


    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    #region VSTO generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

I know some python but C# is definitely another challenge ,

Thanks for your help !

Comment: To write into an Excel file, you can use a library such as OfficeOpenXml

Comment: I'm using the VSTO in Visual Studio , is it possible to integrate it there as well ? Sorry if it's a silly question :p

Comment: I don't know VSTO, but it seems to me that it has another purpose than what you're trying to achieve. It is meant to create solutions that _include_ Excel _as an application_, but what you want to do is simply read an Excel file, and a simple library is enough for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

You declare an `Excel.Application xlApp;` but don't initialize it. CLR doesn't know what is  `xlApp` in line `xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\Microsoft\B1.xlsx");`.
Replace `Excel.Application xlApp;` with `Excel.Application xlApp = Application;`